# ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs) when calculating the loss inside a GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement an attention based encoder-decoder for image captioning following a paper and this the model I implemented:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from ..layers.encoder import Encoder
from ..layers.decoder import Decoder


class CaptionerModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, tokenizer_wrapper, embedding_dim=256, units=512):
        """
        Constructor method for the CaptionerModel class.
        :param units: The number of units to use in the GRU layer
        """

        tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

        super(CaptionerModel, self).__init__()
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer_wrapper.tokenizer
        self.vocab_size = len(self.tokenizer.word_index) + 1
        self.max_length = tokenizer_wrapper.max_length
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.units = units

        # encoder layers
        self.encoder = Encoder(embedding_dim)

        # decoder layer
        self.decoder = Decoder(self.embedding_dim, self.units, self.vocab_size)

    def call(self, data):
        """
        This method performs the forward pass of the model.
        :param images: Input images
        :param importance_features: Importance features for the images
        :param captions: Target captions
        :return: Predicted captions
        """

        # get the images, importance features and captions
        images, importance_features, captions = data

        # initialise the loss
        loss = 0

        # initialise the hidden state
        hidden = self.decoder.reset_state(batch_size=images.shape[0])

        # create the decoder input (which is the start token)
        dec_input = tf.expand_dims([self.tokenizer.word_index["<start>"]] * images.shape[0], 1)

        # get the image features
        features = self.encoder(images, importance_features)

        # iterate over the captions
        for i in range(1, captions.shape[1]):

            # get the predictions
            predictions, hidden, _ = self.decoder(dec_input, features, hidden)

            # calculate the loss
            loss += self.loss_function(captions[:, i], predictions)

            # use teacher forcing
            dec_input = tf.expand_dims(captions[:, i], 1)

        # calculate the batch loss
        batch_loss = (loss / int(captions.shape[1]))

        return batch_loss

    def train_step(self, data):
        """
        This method performs a single training step.
        :param data: The data to train on in the form of a tuple of (images, importance_features, captions)
        """
        images, importance_features, captions = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            l = self((images, importance_features, captions))

        # get the trainable variables
        trainable_variables = self.encoder.trainable_variables + self.decoder.trainable_variables

        # calculate the gradients
        gradients = tape.gradient(l, trainable_variables)

        # apply the gradients
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))

        # update the metrics
        self.loss(l)

        return {"loss": self.loss.result()}
    
    def loss_function(self, real, pred):
        """
        This method calculates the loss.
        """
        mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
        loss_ = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(real, pred, from_logits=True)

        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
        loss_ *= mask

        return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)
```

The problem happens when i try running the `.fit()` method of my model, and i get the error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

I tried compiling the model with `run_eagerly=True`, as well as `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`, but the error message still remains the same.

I did some debugging of my own, setting some breakpoints along the way to see where the program stops exactly, and this is what i came up with:

- breakpoint on the `return batch_loss` inside the `.call()` function (which is called by `self()`): shows that t he return value `batch_loss` has a type of `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.7348917>`, which is the expected value.
- A breakpoint on the `l = self((images, importance_features, captions))` line: never activates

This shows that the problem stems from the call to `return batch_loss`, inside the `self()` call, but I have no idea why.

EDIT: after further investigation, the `train_step()` method is not called. The `call()` itself is being called somewhere through the `fit()` method.

For reproduction purpose, I have updated the [git repo](https://github.com/OmarAtyqy/attention-based-captioning) to include a runnable `main.py` file that should wield the same error.

Comment: Is it possible to provide some dummy data, along with the call to `fit()`, for reproduction?

Comment: @MKimiSH i have updated the question with a github repo, Running the main.py file should yield the same error.